# Text fields are not displayed on the barchart created using jfreechart in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jfreechart, rcp

The Barchart title, domain axis name, range axis name are not visible on barchart when i am displaying barchart using Jfreechart on a view in eclipse RCP plugin.

The code that displays the barchart on a view

```
            final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
            final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

            final ChartComposite frame = new    ChartComposite(barchartComposite,SWT.NONE,chart,true);
            frame.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setChart(chart);
            frame.forceRedraw();
            barchartComposite.getLayout();


 private CategoryDataset createDataset() {

    // row keys...
    final String series1 = "First";


    // column keys...
    final String category1 = "error";
    final String category2 = "info";
    final String category3 = "warning";
    final String category4 = "critical";


    // create the dataset...
    final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    dataset.addValue(10, series1, category1);
    dataset.addValue(5, series1, category2);
    dataset.addValue(6, series1, category3);
    dataset.addValue(9, series1, category4);


    return dataset;

}

  private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

    // create the chart...
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
        "Priority BarChart",         // chart title
        "priority",               // domain axis label
        "Value",                  // range axis label
        dataset,                  // data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
        true,                     // include legend
        true,                     // tooltips?
        false                     // URLs?
    );

    // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...

    // set the background color for the chart...
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
    final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    // set the range axis to display integers only...
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

    // disable bar outlines...
    final BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);

    // set up gradient paints for series...
    final GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
        0.0f, 0.0f, Color.blue, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray
    );

    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);


    final CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
        CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0)
    );
    // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.

    return chart;

}
```

The above code creates a barchart on a view in eclipse RCP plugin.
The method createdataset() generates the data for the graph
The method createChart() generates the chart

Comment: With reference to tags, is this an SWT problem?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the error with `jfreechart-1.0.14`. It seems to be a bug in `ChartComposite` in version 1.0.14.

**Solution**:

You can use the libraries of [jfreechart-1.0.13](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/1.%20JFreeChart/1.0.13/). I have tested it with the code in your question, and it works.

There is also an entry in the jfreechart [bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3482106&group_id=15494&atid=115494).

Quote:

> There is a fix for this within patch 3506228. The fix will be included
>   in the upcoming 1.0.15 release.

Comment: See also the latest branch [NEWS](http://jfreechart.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jfreechart/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/).